# Suggestion needed for this Hive Query

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a select statement with 5 ID columns. I need to lookup and select the corresponding customer names from a Customer master table that stores Ids/names and come up with a Customer report. The tables columns are as below:
origCustomerID,Tier1PartnerID,Tier2PartnerID,DistributorId,EndCustomerID,productId,OrderTotal,OrderDate

The first 5 columns are ID columns that match CustID column in the Customers table. Note that NOT all of these columns will contain a value for a given record at all times, i.e. they could be null at times. Given the current constraints in hiveQL, I can only think of the following way, but this takes up a lot of time and is not the best possible way. Could you please suggest any improvements to this?

```
Select origCustomerID,a.name,Tier1PartnerID,b.name,Tier2PartnerID,
c.name,DistributorId,d.name,EndCustomerID,e.name,productId,OrderTotal,OrderDate 
From Orders O
LEFT OUTER JOIN customers a on o.origCustomerID = a.custid
LEFT OUTER JOIN customers b on o.Tier1PartnerID = a.custid
LEFT OUTER JOIN customers c on o.Tier2PartnerID = a.custid
LEFT OUTER JOIN customers d on o.DistributorId = a.custid
LEFT OUTER JOIN customers e on o.EndCustomerID = a.custid
```

Answer (score 0):

If the id values are always either customer ids or `NULL` (i.e. in the case they are not `NULL` you are sure they are customer ids and not something else) and each record in the `Orders` table matches at most one customer (i.e. every record has at most one id in those five columns; or possible the same id several times), you could perhaps use `COALESCE` in your matching expression.

I can't test this at the moment, but this should join the records using the first non-`NULL` id from the `Orders` table.

```
SELECT [stuff]
FROM Orders O
LEFT OUTER JOIN customers a
ON COALESCE(o.origCustomerID, 
            o.Tier1PartnerID, 
            o.Tier2PartnerID, 
            o.DistributorId, 
            o.EndCustomerID) = a.custid
```

Hope that helps.